# CGAffineTransformMakeRotation on AnnotationViews

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkannotationview, cgaffinetransform

I am trying to adjust the rotation of some annotation views according to their directions by means of `CGAffineTransformMakeRotation`.
Yet my testing of this function gives weird results: if I apply a rotation of `M_PI/2`, as in the example in the code, it points slightly downward, if I use `M_PI` it point all the way down, and at `M_PI/4` it points to the bottom on the left. How is that rotation calculated instead of pointing to the input angle in radians? This is the chunk of code I use:

```
BOOL oldVerticalInverted=NO;
#define degreesToRadians(x) (M_PI * x / 180.0)
#define radiandsToDegrees(x) (x * 180.0 / M_PI)

-(void)adjustAnnotationFor:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)start ToCoordinates:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)end completion:(void (^)(void))completion{
 float newCoordinatesAngle=[Line angleFromCoordinate:start toCoordinate:end];
 float newAngle=newCoordinatesAngle-M_PI/4;
 float angle2Rotate=newAngle-self.angle;
 angle2Rotate=M_PI; //testing
 NSLog(@"oldAngle=%f newAngle=%f angle to rotate=%f %@",   radiandsToDegrees(self.angle), radiandsToDegrees(newAngle), radiandsToDegrees(angle2Rotate), cos(self.angle)<0?@"inverted": @"straight");
 self.angle=newAngle;

 NSLog(@"setting angle to %f cos=%f", self.angle, cos(self.angle));
 if (view!=nil){
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [UIView animateWithDuration:.5 animations:^{
            BOOL verticallyInverted=cos(self.angle)<0;
            int invertVertical=oldVerticalInverted==verticallyInverted?1:-1;
            oldVerticalInverted=verticallyInverted;
            CGAffineTransform affineInvert=CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1, invertVertical);
            CGAffineTransform rotateAffine=CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(angle2Rotate);
            view.transform=CGAffineTransformConcat(rotateAffine, affineInvert);
        }
                        completion :^(BOOL finished){
                            if (completion) completion();
                        }];
    });
 }

}
```

Comment: Looking into the developer website https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGAffineTransform/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGAffineTransformRotate, it states the following,

The angle, in radians, by which to rotate the affine transform. In iOS, a positive value specifies counterclockwise rotation and a negative value specifies clockwise rotation.

Comment: Yes, thanks. The calculation I did was fine, the problem was in CGAffineTransformMakeRotation. When I simply used CGAffineTransformRotate on the view transform in the drawRect method, everything returned in order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a matter of fact, for a reason I ignore, it was enough to assign the angle in the animation for the annotation view to appropriately rotate: this is the upadated code including a chunk for reversing the annotation if pointing towards the left:
    BOOL oldVerticalInverted=NO;
    #define degreesToRadians(x) (M_PI * x / 180.0)
    #define radiandsToDegrees(x) (x * 180.0 / M_PI)

```
-(void)adjustAnnotationFor:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)start ToCoordinates:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)end completion:(void (^)(void))completion{
    __block float newAngle=[Line angleFromCoordinate:start toCoordinate:end];
    __block float angle2Rotate=self.angle;
    __block BusAnnotation* blockSelf=self;
    __block BOOL blockOldInverted=oldVerticalInverted;
   NSLog(@"setto angle a %f cos=%f", self.angle, cos(self.angle));
   if (view!=nil){
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [UIView animateWithDuration:1 animations:^{
            blockSelf.angle=newAngle;
            BOOL verticallyInverted=cos(blockSelf.angle)<0;
            int invertVertical=blockOldInverted==verticallyInverted?1:-1;
            blockOldInverted=verticallyInverted;
            CGAffineTransform affineInvert=CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1, invertVertical);
            view.transform=CGAffineTransformConcat(CGAffineTransformIdentity, affineInvert);

         }
                        completion :^(BOOL finished){
                            if (completion) completion();
                        }];
     });
 }
}
```

The only remaining issue is how to reverse a text I have burnt inside the annotationView and that would be reversed when pointing towards the left: that is how I make this latter part:

```
-(UIImage *)burnText:(NSString *)text ofBackColor:(UIColor*)color intoImage:(UIImage *)img inRect:(CGRect)aRect font:(UIFont*) font{

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(img.size,NO,0.0);

    CGRect aRectangle = CGRectMake(0,0, img.size.width, img.size.height);
    [img drawInRect:aRectangle];
    NSMutableParagraphStyle *textStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle defaultParagraphStyle] mutableCopy];
    textStyle.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail;
    textStyle.alignment=NSTextAlignmentCenter;

    NSDictionary *dictionary = @{ NSFontAttributeName: font,
                              NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: textStyle,
                              NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor blackColor],
                              NSBackgroundColorAttributeName: color};
    [text drawInRect:aRect withAttributes:dictionary];
    UIImage *theImage=UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();   // extract the image
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();     // clean  up the context.
    theImage.accessibilityValue=text;
    return theImage;
}
```

Comment: Ok, I found the source of the magic: I had
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect{
    self.transform=CGAffineTransformRotate(self.myBusView.transform, myBA.angle);

}
in the AnnotationView turning the angle into an actual rotation. Anyway it works, but for the label that appear reversed int the case of an inversion.